# How to test if the entire string consists of only one particular character

Tags: regex

We want to test if the entire string (string length >=2) consists of only one particular (any of the alphanumeric) character.

In short, the regular expression should ONLY pick up the strings mentioned in "Yes" section and should NOT identify strings mentioned in "NO" section.

-- The YES set ---

```
111111 

000 

AAAA 

bbbbb
```

--- The NO set ---

```
zzzzzBzzz 

3   

0000110
```

We should not choose 3 because the length of this string is 1.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Common mistake, but this isn't a forum, it's a question and answer site. It's required you attempt to resolve your issue as well as be clear as to what it is that you're trying to do. For your question I don't understand how you're caring about string length. You want to test if an entire string is the same character, but only if the size of the string is equal or greater than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9])\1+$
```

This captures the first character and ensures that all characters after that point are the same using a backreference. Also ensures that at least two characters are present.

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/Y66XvR/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot :-). "backreference" does the trick, and I learnt it today. Instead of ^ and $, I use \b.

Answer (score 0):

Callum's answer works perfectly. Now, I would like to move a step forward -- how can we exclude a string if a repetition of any character i.e. (\w) happens.

More precisely, (\w)\1+ captures any repetitions of character. How can we  deselct a string if the above group exists in the string.

-- Yes set ---

abc
12x
1x2
z2v

-- No set ---

abba
11cv
aabb
x33Y

My suggestion is:

^(?!\w*(\w)\1+)\w*

A better suggestion will always be appreciated, sincerely.

Thanks
Sanjoy